# Incluir Pagina aspx en otra aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

espero explicarme, pueden orientarme sobre como incluir una pagina aspx dentro de otra aspx, mi intencion es crear un header pero ese lo utilizare en varios proyectos, y ocupo reutilizar ese codigo, les agradeceria su ayuda.

Nota: intente usar un iframe pero realiza lo que deseo.

Gracias.

Comment: .    Master page    .

Comment: Lo que necesitas en efecto es usar master pages, dale una revisada a esta página http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/tutorial-aspnet-utilizacion-de-master-pages/

Comment: Pero son diferentes proyectos, lo que me piden es realizar algo como si fuera php, que solamente incluyen un archivo y se reutiliza en todas las paginas creadas

Comment: has intentado usar <iframe>

Comment: @LuisMata si intente con un iframe, pero no realiza lo que deseo,

Comment: Para poder mantener el mismo header, tiene que usar master page, en visual studio, yo lo uso y con eso ahorro mucho código, en Visual studio, Nuevo/Proyecto/web y adicionas una página, y como primer archivo adicionas un Web Form con Página Maestra. y las páginas siguientes serían las vinculadas, Formulario Web con Página Maestra, y para borrar la extensión .aspx el nugget Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls, queda excelente.

Comment: Ampliando lo que dicen los demás, podrías utilizar un control de usuario (ascx). Te indico enlace con documentación https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wt3k2fyw(v=vs.100)